# Load More button to create new html tags in Angular

Tags: angular

I found this example for append new tags based on *ngfor statement in Angular, but my problem is every time I send request to the API and return new data it replace the old data, every request include new 10 texts, and I tried to load the other new 10 below the old 10 like this example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/rkTlnnClu7tjHC19UC41?p=preview

main.component.ts:

```
public incCount(loadMore) {
        this.pageNumber = this._newsFeedService.loadMore += 1;
        return this.pageNumber * 10;
    }

    newsFeed() {
        this.user.page = this.incCount(this._newsFeedService.loadMore);
        this._newsFeedService.newsFeedService(this.user)
            .subscribe(
                response => {
                    this.result = response;
                    if (this.result.code == -501) {
                        // this.router.navigate(['/verify'])
                    } else if (this.result.code == 1) {
                        this.data = [];
                        this.result.data.posts.forEach(item => {
                            this.data.push(item);
                        });
                        console.log(this.data);
                    }
                    else {
                        this.alert = this._appService.newAlert('danger', this.result.msg);
                    }
                },
                error => console.log(error)
            );
        console.log(this.user.page);
    }
```

main.component.html:

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of data">
        <article class="hentry post">
            <mat-card>
                <mat-card-header>
...
...
...
  <p>{{item.postText}}</p>
...
...
...
              </mat-card-actions>
            </mat-card>
        </article>
    </div>
<button class="form-control" (click)="newsFeed()" >Load More</button>
```

When I press newsFeed() button, the old text replaced by new text, how can I generate new `<mat-card>` with new 10 text below the old text?

Comment: why not append the return values instead of replacing them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you explicitly say in your code that you want to reset the data on HTTP call success :

```
else if (this.result.code == 1) {
     this.data = []; <- here
```

if you want to add more item to your data you can change this statement by

```
    else if (this.result.code == 1) {
             this.data = this.data || []; // <- will assign new array on the first call, and do nothing if data is already initialized 
             ...
```